# Electron tray icon change depending on dark theme?

Tags: electron

I'm using Electron and trying to develop a tray (menubar) application.

[image]

I know how to set the icon:

```
const {Tray} = require('electron')
appIcon = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')
```

How can I create an icon (or select a different one) that will change color depending on the theme (normal or dark) that the user has selected?

In the above example, I use a dark theme, so I can create a white icon, but what happens when the user has the normal white theme?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be using a template image (only black and clear colors): https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/native-image.md#template-image

That way macOS automatically adjusts your tray icon to be black when on normal theme, and white when on dark theme.

Ensure the filename ends in `Template.png` or it won't work! Also include a `@2x.png` version if you target hi-dpi devices.

So your folder would look like:

```
.
├── main.js
├── IconTemplate.png
└── IconTemplate@2x.png
```

Then in your `main.js`:

```
const {Tray} = require('electron')
appIcon = new Tray('./IconTemplate.png')
```

Comment: Do you have any more information regarding how these images should be created? Are they some sort of sprite map? Dimensions? etc.

Comment: Just a normal `.png` file. Just keep in mind to only use black and transparent colors. On my Mac, 22px for normal dpi and 44px for hi-dpi seems to work well, but test yourself.

Comment: How should this be done on Windows and Ubuntu/Linux?

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to make it work, so here is what I ended up with:

```js
// create a new native image from icon
const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath('some/icon.png');
// if you want to resize it, be careful, it creates a copy
const trayIcon = icon.resize({ width: 16 });
// here is the important part (has to be set on the resized version)
trayIcon.setTemplateImage(true);
const tray = new Tray(trayIcon)
```

The trick is to use the **setTemplateImage(true)**, which I was using, but as the last step I was resizing the icon and the resulting image did not have the template flag set.

Comment: This worked for me, this should be the chosen one!

Answer (score 0):

We build tray icon from SVG to PNG in B&W colors like here:

```js
// File: build/build_tray_icon.ts
// Command: yarn run ts-node build/build_tray_icon.ts

import path from "path"
import sharp from "sharp";
import jsdom from "jsdom"
import fs from "fs-extra"

export async function generateTrayIcon(
  {
    outputFilename = "tray_icon", // e.g. output tray_icon_dark@2x.png
    svgIconPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/renderer/components/icon/logo.svg"),
    outputFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, "./tray"),
    dpiSuffix = "2x",
    pixelSize = 32,
    shouldUseDarkColors = false, // managed by electron.nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors
  } = {}) {
  outputFilename += shouldUseDarkColors ? "_dark" : ""
  dpiSuffix = dpiSuffix !== "1x" ? `@${dpiSuffix}` : ""
  const pngIconDestPath = path.resolve(outputFolder, `${outputFilename}${dpiSuffix}.png`)
  try {
    // Modify .SVG colors
    const trayIconColor = shouldUseDarkColors ? "white" : "black";
    const svgDom = await jsdom.JSDOM.fromFile(svgIconPath);
    const svgRoot = svgDom.window.document.body.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    svgRoot.innerHTML += `<style>* {fill: ${trayIconColor} !important;}</style>`
    const svgIconBuffer = Buffer.from(svgRoot.outerHTML);

    // Resize and convert to .PNG
    const pngIconBuffer: Buffer = await sharp(svgIconBuffer)
      .resize({ width: pixelSize, height: pixelSize })
      .png()
      .toBuffer();

    // Save icon
    await fs.writeFile(pngIconDestPath, pngIconBuffer);
    console.info(`[DONE]: Tray icon saved at "${pngIconDestPath}"`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`[ERROR]: ${err}`);
  }
}

// Run
const iconSizes: Record<string, number> = {
  "1x": 16,
  "2x": 32,
};
Object.entries(iconSizes).forEach(([dpiSuffix, pixelSize]) => {
  generateTrayIcon({ dpiSuffix, pixelSize, shouldUseDarkColors: false });
  generateTrayIcon({ dpiSuffix, pixelSize, shouldUseDarkColors: true });
});
```

And then update your Tray icon on theme-update like here:

```js
import { nativeTheme } from "electron"

// refresh icon when MacOS dark/light theme has changed
nativeTheme.on("updated", () => trayInstance.setImage(getTrayIcon()));

function getTrayIcon(isDark = nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors): string {
  return path.resolve(`/path/to/icons/tray_icon${isDark ? "_dark" : ""}.png`
  )
}
```